# What is the purpose of use using Cardano-graphql & hasura in the same stack?

Tags: wallet, cardano-node, cardano-graphql

I'm in the process of writing some software that will connect to the Cardano networking such as signing transactions & querying historical chain data. During my search for a solution I came across Hasura, which I planned to hook up postgres (using cardano-db-sync as well) to.

Later down the road I found `Cardano-graphql` in the inputoutput github account & noticed in the reference docker file [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql/blob/610424b95053078c20be121d823ef0dd035711f0/docker-compose.yml#L76) that the developers have also chosen to include Hasrua which is also a graphql api.

What is the purpose of this? Do I need both? What is the benifit of using `cardano-graphql` & `hasura` as shown in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hasura](https://hasura.io) is a cloud service where you can deploy `cardano-graphql` in a very easy and straight forward way, since it is oriented to `graphql` APIs.

So no, you don't need both.

`cardano-graphql` is very expensive to use in matter of resources so depending on the type of queries you want to do to the blockchain, maybe you need a service like [Blockfrost](https://www.blockfrost.io/).